# How to replace UISlider with UIProgressView playing MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am having a hard time trying to replace `UISlider` on my app playing a invisible `MPMoviePlayerController` with `UIProgressView`.

`UISlider` is just create, very intuitive to change, Pretty much on the Update selector from `MPMoviePlayerController` I update its current status:

and previously I defined the min and max from the content of the `MPMoviePlayerController`:

```
-(void)UpdateTime:(NSTimer*)Timer
{

[self.sldProgress1 setValue:[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:playerSong.currentPlaybackTime] floatValue]];

}
```

`UIProgressView` doesn't provide similar approach, and I didn't find on the web a sample that matches what I am trying to do:

```
        sldProgress2.maximumValue = [playerSong playableDuration];
        sldProgress1.value = 0.0;
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What about self.sldProgress1.progress = playerSong.currentPlaybackTime;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIProgressView doesn't have the concept of a user-settable max value - it's just 100.0. To make it work as you want, you'll have to do some math. Luckily, it's easy math:

```
CGFloat percentComplete = [playerSong.currentPlaybackTime floatValue] / [playerSong.playableDuration floatValue];
```

That will give you the percentage of the song that's complete, and you just update your UIProgressView to that number.

```
progressView.progress = percentComplete;
```

More or less - this code was mostly pseudo based on your question, but that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using the UISlider and hide the thumbImage using this line:

```
[mySlider setThumbImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This worked for me.